# UIActivityIndicator scrolls with tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a table view controller .When I start activity indicator to animate and then scroll the table view , activity indicator starts to scroll with that .
I have tried to set a specific location for activity indicator and also add it as subview of vew .This is the codes that I have written for that :

```
spinner.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 2  - (spinner.frame.size.width / 2)
spinner.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height  - (self.tableView.rowHeight / 2 )
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
self.view.addSubview(spinner)
```

What's wrong with that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also do this: `[self.view.superview addSubview:spinner];`, this add the spinner to the window, just remember to remove it when `viewDidDisappear`,  also `spinner.center = self.view.center;` this will center it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a `UITableViewController` then `self.view` is the table (the same as `self.tableView`). You are adding the spinner to the table so when the table scrolls, the spinner scrolls too.

To avoid this, don't use a `UITableViewController`. Use a simple `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` to it. Then `self.view` won't scroll.

Comment: thanks, Is it possible to make `UITableViewController` as subclass of `UIViewController` ? Because using `UITableViewController` is very helpful.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is already a subclass of `UIViewController` but the condition is there is only the table in the controller and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = indicator;
```

might help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10926043)

Comment: he wants a non scrolling spinner on a table view background. my answer perfectly provides that...