# UIActivityIndicator is not moving up when scrolled in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UITableviewcontroller and a activity indicator added to it. 
When ever my table scroll, the indicator also moves up and goes out of bounds. Instead I want to display indicator even if the table scrolls

I checked this post: [UIActivityIndicator scrolls with tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049593/uiactivityindicator-scrolls-with-tableview) which says I need to use UIViewcontroller instead of Tableviewcontroller.

Since I have many tableviewcontrollers added in application, isnt it possible to scroll indicator along with tableview.

My UIActivityIndicator is helper class across entire application where I control to display and remove spinner

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func displaySpinner(onView : UIView) -> UIView {
        let spinnerView = UIView.init(frame: onView.frame)
        spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        ai.startAnimating()
        ai.center = spinnerView.center

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinnerView.addSubview(ai)
            onView.addSubview(spinnerView)
        }

        return spinnerView
    }

    class func removeSpinner(spinner :UIView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinner.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if it's not an extension say the code is inside the tableController and

```
let indicator = UIActivityIndicator()
```

then use

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  // change frame of indicator by scrollview.contentOffset.y
}
```

---

You can also extend

```
class MyTableConWithIndicator:UITableViewController {

   let indicator = UIActivityIndicator()

   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     // change y'frame of indicator by scrollview.contentOffset.y
   }
   func addIndicator() {}
   func removeIndicator() ()
}
```

Then extend from it in every tableController

```
class MyTable:MyTableConWithIndicator {}
```